# Continuous Surjection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\{0,1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Its clear that one can continuously map $\mathbb{R}$ onto $\{1\}$...however, what about mapping it continuously onto $\{0,1\}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 different topologies that you can have on $\{0,1\}$, two of which are homeomorphic. The answer to your question depends on which topology you're working on.

Comment: There's the trivial topology, the discrete topology (equivalent to the restriction of the Euclidean topology) and what else?

Also right, it's true wrt trivial topology since $f^{-1}(\{0,1\}) = \mathbb{R}$!  Nice!

Comment: @ProbablyAHuman There is the topology where $\{0\}$ is open but $\{1\}$ is not.

Comment: In the non-trivial and non-discrete case (ie: the case you point out $\tau=\{\{0\},\{0,1\},\emptyset\}$) what would the continuous functions be?

I ask here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3592883/continuous-functions-from-mathbbr-to-0-1

Comment: @ProbablyAHuman I just saw your question, and you got a good answer to it ;)

Answer (score 0):

That cannot be done, because $\mathbb R$ is connected. Therefore, if $f\colon\mathbb R\longrightarrow\{0,1\}$ is continuous, then $f(\mathbb R)$ is connected. And the only non-empty connected subsets of $\{0,1\}$ are $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$.