# Continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\{0,1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $\{0,1\}$ be equipped with the topology suggested by Scientifica in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3591657/continuous-surjection-from-mathbbr-onto-0-1/3591660#3591660), ie: $\tau=\{\emptyset, \{0,1\},\{0\}\}$.  What are the continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(\{0,1\},\tau)$?

Comment: $(\{0,1\},\tau)$ is called Sierpinski space.

Comment: Does the $n$-fold product of such spaces also have a name?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: The aswer is very short: this set of functions is bijectively parametrized by the open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. For such $U\subset \mathbb{R}$, define $\varphi_U$ as the characteristic function of $\mathbb{R}\setminus U$, then the collection $$\{\varphi_U\}$$ is exactly the set you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function is continuous iff the inverse image of all open sets are open. Since $f^{-}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and $f^{-1}(\{0,1\}=\mathbb{R}$, a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ will be continuous iff $f^{-1}(0)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, therefore $f^{-1}(0)$ has to be a countable union of disjoint open intervals, so the only continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{0,1\}$ with that topology are the [characteristic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function) of complements of open sets of $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. characteristic functions of closed sets in $\mathbb{R}$, i.e. characteristic functions of complements of countable disjoint unions of open intervals.